# SQL select rand and update the results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this banners system to run on my website. I have a SQL table which stores id, link, title, prints and clicks among other stuff.

So, I need to print them randomly on given pages, and update the prints coloumn (which is how many times this banner has been shown) with prints + 1 value. I'm doing with 2 queries, on for the select and then one for the update, but i know it is possible to do with only one query, but I've heard it's not so healthy for SQL + PHP. However, when I run the script, it adds the value twice, where it should be one print more, it added 2. Already checked if the script is running twice per id, but it is not, it is running normally. The code is the following:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM banners WHERE (NOW() BETWEEN ban_start_date AND ban_final_date) AND ban_paid = "y" AND ban_active = "a" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3';
    $query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($response = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        extract($response); 
        $banners[] = array('id' => $ban_id, 'code' => $ban_code, 'img' => $ban_img, 'title' => $ban_title, 'link' => $ban_link, 'prints' => $ban_prints);
        $ban_qr = 'UPDATE banners SET ban_prints = ban_prints + 1 WHERE ban_id = "' . $ban_id . '"';
        $ban_qr = mysql_query($ban_qr) or die(mysql_error);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you prefix every column with `ban_` in your table definition? Seems redundant as every row in the banners table is a banner.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot both select rows and update them in one query. You can update all the rows you selected in one query (use `WHERE ban_id IN (list of IDs)`), but you still need two queries minimum.

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
        `ban_id` AS `id`, 
        `ban_code` AS `code`, 
        `ban_img` AS `img`, 
        `ban_title` AS `title`, 
        `ban_link` AS `link`, 
        `ban_prints` AS `prints` 
    FROM
        `banners`
    WHERE 
        `ban_paid` = 'y'
    AND 
        `ban_active` = 'a'
    AND
        `ban_start_date` < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    AND
        `ban_final_date` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ORDER BY
        RAND()
    LIMIT 
        3
    ";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $banners[] = $row;
  $ids[] = $row['id'];
}

$query = "
    UPDATE 
        `banners` 
    SET 
        `ban_prints` = `ban_prints` + 1 
    WHERE 
        `ban_id` IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ")
    ";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```